# Patch not installing in Magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-10336

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Comment: What is the patch you are applied?

Comment: i am using SUPEE-10336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely if `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv` is modified the patch process will fail. If there has been any changes to it for locale (verbiage) then you'll want to simply copy down the core file over existing, be sure to make a backup copy before hand, and re-apply the patch. If successful you'll want to manually make the change in your backup copy csv file, and then move it (rename) it back afterwards.

Also, the patch bash `.sh` file will also have the `.patch` file contents were you can see the changes it is attempting to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to manually patch the Mage_USA.csv file and remove the respective line from the patch script.
Patch SUPEE-10336 does the following to the Mage_USA.csv file:

```
diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
index 072170d..5e8f844 100644
--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
 "First-Class Mail Large Envelope","First-Class Mail Large Envelope"
 "First-Class Mail Large Postcards","First-Class Mail Large Postcards"
 "First-Class Mail Letter","First-Class Mail Letter"
-"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"
+"First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"
 "First-Class Mail Postcards","First-Class Mail Postcards"
 "First-Class Package International Service","First-Class Package International Service"
 "First-Class Package Service","First-Class Package Service"
```

Remove the above code in your patch.sh file.
Now, copy the Mage_USA file to your local machine and change this row:

> "First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"

To this:

> "First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"

Install your patch and upload your amended file.